# How can I get the criteria to change in a CountIf function in VBA as a loop progresses?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, countif

```
week = 1
y = 3
z = 18

For l = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)

    Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("B2:B250"), week)
    x = Range("A1").Value

    pf1 = "=IF("
    pf2 = l
    pf3 = "3=1,VLOOKUP($L3,$C$"
    pf4 = y
    pf5 = ":$F$"
    pf6 = z
    pf7 = ",3,FALSE),VLOOKUP($L3,$D$"
    pf8 = ":$F$"
    pf9 = ",3,FALSE))"
    pf = pf1 + pf2 + pf3 + pf4 + pf5 + pf6 + pf7 + pf4 + pf8 + pf6 + pf9

    If x = 14 Then
        y = 14 + y
        z = 13 + z
    End If

    If x = 15 Then
        y = 15 + y
        z = 14 + z
    End If

    If x = 16 Then
        y = 16 + y
        z = 15 + z
    End If

    pfrng.Offset(0, j * 6) = pf
    
    j = j + 1
    week = week + 1
    
    Range("A1").ClearContents
Next l
```

I want the script above to recognize and change the value of the variable "week" as I loop through the lower bound of my array (arr1) to the upper bound. While doing so, it must also increase the y and z values accordingly.

Also, is this the correct method I should be using, or is there something better/more efficient or something with a cleaner appearance?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would combine your `pf` statement into one line. Also, you concatenate strings with `&` in VBA, not `+`

Comment: It looks like you are already incrementing `week`. Does your code run? Do you get an error? Also, what is the variable `pf`? Range?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you need to do, so it's difficult for us to know if your code is correct or if there's a "better" way to do it.

Comment: @urdearboy Yes, the code runs but I should have given a little more background on the worksheet that I'm running it on. I have a column of 250+ numbers that range from 1 to 17. I want to count the amount of times that each number appears within the column and set that "count" equal to the variable "x".

Comment: @TimWilliams, The array that I am iterating through are letters I want to assign to the variable "l" which will act as the correct column for the reference I'm making with the whole "pf" statement.

Comment: If more information is needed just let me know what would help the most.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?  How does the outcome of your script differ from what you want?  You can use `x = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("B2:B250"), week)` instead of setting the value to a cell and then reading it from there.